# Swiper Slider Mouse Scroll And Looping Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, swiper.js

I am using the swiper slider to horizontally scroll trough my slideshow. I want that my content is looping, but for any reasons its only repeating once and than it stops.

My swiper slider setup looks like this:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  direction: "horizontal",
  mousewheelControl: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  freeMode: true,
  followFinger: true,
  loop: true
});
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Dennisade/pen/ZPygbr

I appreciate any help

Comment: `loop: true,` will work, check in your codepen. you forgot it in you running code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I also tried it with `loop:true` but its also not working while scrolling the slider. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Swiper version 4.5.0, there are three things that cause errors in your code :

- First thing, you added a `swiper-wrapper` div around every slide. You only need one `swiper-wrapper` div that wraps all your slides.
- Second thing, when you set `slidesPerView: 'auto'` along with `loop: true`, you need to provide the total number of looped slides and add it in the `loopedSlides` parameter.
  Checkout the doc in Parameters > slidesPerView : https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters.
- Last thing, `mousewheelControl` parameter is not used anymore, you need the `mousewheel` parameter (https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#mousewheel-control) like so :

```
mousewheel: {
  releaseOnEdges: true,
},
```

You can also drop `direction: "horizontal"` and `followFinger: true` in this case.

So the solution is :

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  freeMode: true,
  loop: true,
  loopedSlides: 8 // according to the codepen
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  },
});
```

Checkout your codepen I forked that works : https://codepen.io/olig/pen/rgmPyb

Comment: Its possible to have a smooth scroll like this https://sudo.isl.co/translate-vertical-horizontal/#UX-Primer

Comment: It's a different logic. Even though it looks like a slider, it's not. It's more of a scroll logic. Check out gsap's [scrolltrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/). That may help you.